# SQL Outer Join while conditioning on an extra column

Tags: join, query

I am trying to pull up an outer join between two tables, on a specifc column "Identifier", however, I would only like to carry out the outer joins on the rows where additional column "Date" matches between the tables. Example of what I am trying to achieve is, for the two tables below:

```
+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Date       | Identifier    | TableA-Attribute1 |TableA-Attribute2|
+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| date1      |         Id1   | a                 | x               |
| date1      |         Id2   | b                 | y               |
| date1      |         Id3   | c                 | z               |
| date2      |         Id1   | d                 | x               |
| date2      |         Id2   | e                 | y               |
+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+


+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Date       | Identifier    | TableB-Attribute1 |TableB-Attribute2|
+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| date1      |         Id1   | aa                | xx              |
| date1      |         Id2   | bb                | yy              |
| date1      |         Id3   | cc                | zz              |
| date1      |         Id4   | dd                | xx              |
| date2      |         Id1   | ee                | yy              |
+------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

I need to end up with something that looks like this:

```
+------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
| Date       | Identifier    | A-Attr1 |A-Attr2|B-Attr1 |B-Attr2|
+------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
| date1      |         Id1   | a       | x     |aa      |xx     |
| date1      |         Id2   | b       | y     |bb      |yy     |
| date1      |         Id3   | c       | z     |cc      |zz     |
| date1      |         Id4   | -       | -     |dd      |xx     |
| date2      |         Id1   | d       | x     |ee      |yy     |
| date2      |         Id2   | e       | y     |-       |-      |
+------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

I was trying to do something like this

> go
>   select * from 
>   table1 full outer join (select * from table2 where table1.date=table2.date)

however, that unfortunately does not seem to be working.

Comment: What is the DBMS? Is it SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need subqueries. You only need to use both columns in the `ON` condition of the `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    -- t1.*,     -- adjust, keep only 
    -- t2.*,     -- needed columns
    COALESCE(t1.date, t2.date)
                  AS date, 
    COALESCE(t1.identifier, t2.identifier)
                  AS identifier, 
    t1.attribute1 AS a_attribute1,
    t1.attribute2 AS a_attribute2,
    t2.attribute1 AS b_attribute1,
    t2.attribute2 AS b_attribute2
FROM table1 AS t1 
     FULL JOIN table2 AS t2
     ON  t1. date = t2. date
     AND t1. identifier= t2. identifier
-- WHERE
--     (t1.date = '2000-01-01' OR t2.date = '2000-01-01')
 ;
```

If we want date and identifier combined in one column each, we can use `COALESCE()` function.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Can I just follow up on this - Do you maybe know how can I filter the results by date. I've been trying to do that by just doing--> select * from (*your query*) as p where p.date='2000-01-01', but I am getting the Error message "The column 'date' was specified multiple times for 'p'."

Comment: See the edit. Don't use `t1.^, t2.*`, keep only the columns you need.

Comment: Filtering on a FULL join can be tricky. You need to either filter on both tables (see my example in the answer) or use filters in derived tables first and then (full) join.